# How can I put conditionals in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm having problems when I'm trying to put a condition in params in my controller. This code is inside my controller:

```
if params[:example] == 1
   @table = Model.find(:all,:conditions=>['column_table= ?',params[:example]  ]  )
else
   @table = Model.find(:all,:conditions=>['column_table2= ?',params[:example]  ]  )
end
```

Is this code correct? How can I put a conditional in params controller?

Comment: First of all check  raise params[:example].inspect

Comment: what problem are you having , show the error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code looks okay. Unfortunately you do not say what problem you have. The only thing I see that may fail is the condition. If you pass some value into your params they are not typecasted. Therefore I guess you should use `to_i` in your condition:

```
if params[:example].to_i == 1
  ...
```

Comment: THanks spickermann it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
@table = Model.where((params[:example] == 1 ? 'column_table= ?' : 'column_table2 = ?'), params[:example]) unless params[:example].blank?
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code. You have save params[:example] in one variable.and use your coditions.

```
if params[:example].present?
    @example = params[:example]
   if @example == 1
    @table = Model.find(:all,:conditions=>['column_table= ?',params[:example]  ]  )
    else
   @table = Model.find(:all,:conditions=>['column_table2= ?',params[:example]  ]  )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also send the column name along with its value and avoid ifs

```
@table = Model.find(:all,:conditions=>["#{params[:col]} = ?", params[:example]  ]  )
```

Comment: thanks is another help :)